# How to implement a method, into interface, with parameter and returned value generic in C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I would like to implement a interface with generic input parameter and returned value in C#.
At the moment I have defined a interface:

```
interface IResponseFormatter
{
    T formatResponseOptimizated<T>(T[] tagsValues);
}
```

after that I have tried to implement a concrete class:

```
public class FormatResponseInterpolatedData : IResponseFormatter

{
    ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HistorianPersistenceImpl));



    public Dictionary<string, List<object[]>> formatResponseOptimizated <Dictionary<string, List<object[]>>> (IHU_RETRIEVED_DATA_VALUES[] tagsValues)
    {
        log.Info("ENTER [formatResponseOptimizated] tagValues: " + tagsValues);
        Dictionary<string, List<object[]>> result = new Dictionary<string, List<object[]>>();

        // built data logic

        return result;
    }
}
```

I would like to understand what I'm wrong about and how I can to make this implementation type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining a generic method in a non-generic interface.

Move `T` from being `formatResponseOptimizated` type parameter to `IResponseFormatter` type parameter, and provide a specification in the implementing class:

```
interface IResponseFormatter<T> {
    // Follow C# naming conventions: method names start in an upper case letter
    T FormatResponseOptimizated(T[] tagsValues);
}
public class FormatResponseInterpolatedData
     : IResponseFormatter<Dictionary<string,List<object[]>>> {
    public Dictionary<string,List<object[]>> FormatResponseOptimizated(Dictionary<string,List<object[]>>[] tagsValues) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that with a single type parameter `T` the return type of `FormatResponseOptimizated` must match the type of array element that it takes as its parameter `T[]`. If the two should be different, parameterize your interface on two types, say, `TArg` for the argument and `TRet` for return.

Comment: it works thanks. But I corrected interface with IResponseFormatter<T,U> with the followed method: 
T formatResponseOptimizated(U[] tagsValues); 

So in the class implemented I have:  

public Dictionary<string, List<object[]>> formatResponseOptimizated(IHU_RETRIEVED_DATA_VALUES[] tagsValues)

Comment: @Stefano Right, that's what I mentioned in the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I show corrected implementation:

**Interface**:

```
interface IResponseFormatter<T,U>
{
    T formatResponseOptimizated(U[] tagsValues);
}
```

**Implemented Class:**

```
public class FormatResponseInterpolatedData : IResponseFormatter<Dictionary<string, List<object[]>>, IHU_RETRIEVED_DATA_VALUES>

{

    public Dictionary<string, List<object[]>> formatResponseOptimizated(IHU_RETRIEVED_DATA_VALUES[] tagsValues)
    {
        // implemented data logic
    }
}
```

Thanks